# Preservation of baked goods with eggs

Tags: food-preservation

When you bake (cookies etc) commercially with egg in your recipe, do you have to add any preservatives and if so, what?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we explicitly don't discuss commercial cooking and baking. Please see the [help] for more info.

Comment: and apologies if I violated some rules, will go and read up in the "help center".

Comment: @Stephie that new? rule isn't very obvious from the help center FAQs, maybe link to the relevant meta thread? In any way, I do not disagree with considering commercial preservation via non-GRAS additives being best considered off topic - tends to attract questions that come too close to "strangers on the internet can take more responsibility than me for my usage of a biocidal additive" ;)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: no. I cooked/baked commercially for years, and never used any sort of preservative/stabilizer. The cooking (baking) process is what stabilizes the product. The egg only goes 'bad' from a raw state, not cooked.

Comment: thank you ever so much for the quick feedback.  I just wanted to make 100% sure.